# kde density plot using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I was following the "python for data analysis" in ipython, trying to do a kde plot using pandas(chapter 8, Histograms and Density Plots).the codes are simple:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
ser = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000))
ser.plot(kind='kde')
```

the error is

```
UnboundLocalError:local variable 'klass' referenced before assignment
```

I googled around and I think it is a local&global variable problem and may be due to a wrong way to import the modules. Anybody can suggest any ideas?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Are you sure you are running %pylab?

Comment: Which version of `pandas` are you running?  `print(pd.__version__)`.  I suspect it's pre-0.8, in which case you should take this opportunity to upgrade to `0.10.1`.

Comment: The problem resolved after pandas be updated. Thank you very much!